# What the difference between df[:,'column_name'] and df['column_name'] when querying data from a pandas.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What the difference between `df[:,'column_name']` and `df['column_name']` when querying data from pandas's DataFrame.

When I use `df[:,'Energy_supply']` I come into this

> > TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'.

But when I use `df['column_name']` I get what I want.

My data is a 228 rows × 3 columns dataframe with a country_name index and the three columns' name are `['Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']`.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkLCs.png)

Comment: df[:,'index'] is for accessing elements from an array

Comment: Welcome on SO, please add the image directly in the question. Also take the [tour] and see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['index']
```

is for accessing to the column 'index' not for specific data.

Note that in python (Numpy), you can access the data by  `df[:, 2]` [line, column]

In Pandas use, instead :

```
df.loc[:, 'index'] # [line number, column 'index'], : means all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[:,'index']
```

is for accessing elements from an array (slice operation), index is the column index 
 (0 to n-1)

Equivalent operation for pandas is

```
df.loc[:,int_index]


df['column_name'] is for accessing columns from a pandas data frame.
```

Have a look at this:

https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/